# Can't put prototype functions in promise resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Using Node.js's [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), when I try to pass an object prototype function to a `.then` resolver in a promise, it's losing context of `this`:

```
Foo.prototype.outsideResolve = function() {
    var that = this;
    return q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log(that); // {data: "foo"}
        resolve();
    });
};

Foo.prototype.insideResolve = function() {
    var that = this;
    return q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log(that); // undefined
        resolve();
    });
};

Foo.prototype.async = function() {
    var foo = this;

    return q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        foo.outsideResolve()
            .then(foo.insideResolve)
            .then(resolve)
            .fail(reject)
            .done();
    });
};
```

Why does this happen? Is this expected behavior? Are you not supposed to be able to call prototype functions in promise resolves? Is there a way around this?

Comment: `.then(this.insideResolve.bind(this))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is not a static thing. It can change based on what the function using `this` is being invoked on. In some cases, this can be the object you've just invoked new on, but in this instance, it's not.

When you reach `foo.insideResolve` from the promise chain, the ThisBinding is lost. In order to fix this you can use the `Function.prototype.bind` method, which takes a varadic number of arguments - the first argument is the `this` context you want to bind the function to use, and the others are arguments that are partially applied. The `bind` function returns a function which when invoked passes the `this` and arguments to the original function.

In short:

use `foo.insideResolve.bind(foo)` instead of `foo.insideResolve`.

Comment: Thanks to you and elclanrs. Using `.bind` does do the trick. But I am still confused on why the `this` context is lost inside the promise resolve. If we have a reference to `foo` and we're clearly calling `foo`'s `insideResolve` function, shouldn't `this` still evaluate to that object?

Comment: it is a bit difficult to explain but essentially, no. I can't explain it very well but there is an [excellent blog post](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/) that might help. The long and short of it though is that you basically don't want to rely on `this` being a certain value (this is a reason why some people prefer to avoid `this`).

Comment: The thing is that you *don't* keep a reference to foo when you write `foo.insideResolve` (without parentheses to call the function right there). You merely get a reference to the `insideResolve` function itself, and the fact that you found that reference via a property of `foo` is lost. Inside a function, `this` is determined when the function is *called*, not when you previously obtained a reference to the function. The promise calls `insideResolve` without any knowledge that it was a property of `foo`; all it has at the time of the call is the function itself.

Comment: And that's why `bind` fixes it. As you can see in Dan's code, the parameter passed to `bind` is a reference to the object you want to use when the function is ultimately called. `bind` holds that reference in a closure and uses it when it calls the original function for you.